# How to Document WordPress Theme/Plugin's Filters/Actions with PHP Comments

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm seeking some advice for how to generate documentation for filters and actions that are apart of a theme or plugin.

As a WordPress developer, it would be helpful to generate documentation for these custom filters and actions through PHP comments in my projects. Say for example something like this:

```
/**
 * A short description.
 *
 * A summary.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @filter plugin_post_types
 */
$post_types = apply_filters('plugin_post_types', $post_types);
```

Or something along those lines.

I've tried giving PHPDocumentor and ApiGen a shot, but they focus more on classes, methods, etc.

Does anyone know of a current solution to this? Or perhaps someone could share some insight on how they handle a similar situation. I'd really rather not have to write the documentation by hand lol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On a personal note - I would say whatever fits you is good enough as long as you stick to it. PHPDoc should be perfect.

Putting personal note aside - if we talk about WordPress development then their coding standards are defined very well.

Please head to their documentation page and you can find examples of how they want hooks (actions and filters) to be documented:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/inline-documentation-standards/php/#4-hooks-actions-and-filters